# SQL Query for fetching data from different sheets and form one temporary table on monthly Basis

Tags: mysql, excel

I have two sheets in excel.
departure sheet has columns: Month and name

| MONTH | Name |
| --- | --- |
| April | Michael |
| April | Danny |

arrival sheet has columns: Month and name

| MONTH | Name |
| --- | --- |
| April | Sunny |
| April | Sam |

I have to create a temporary table in which i have to

1. fetch data from these two sheets together
   and create a third column called status that will tell record is coming from departure/arrival sheet
2. This will happen every month, so every month whenever a person runs the query then those record will append in this table automatically

| MONTH | Name | Status. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| April | Michael | Departure |
| April | Danny | Departure |
| April | Sunny | Arrival |
| April | Sam | Arrival |

I was thinking of case when but i am getting stuck since its coming from various sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on what sheet you are using? If you are using GSheet you could look at [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax) that the 'from' clause can actually refer to other sheets.

Comment: No its not gsheet